# How can I add fixed-data-table to my react.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm wanting to display data in a table and `fixed-data-table` is perfect. I'm new to react.rs and node.js but I simply want to be able to render `fixed-data-table`'s tables to the HMTL page but having problems to integrate it into my sample app.

I tried to add `fixed-data-table`'s dist 'js' and 'css' file and added this to my 'example.js'

```
var Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
var Column = FixedDataTable.Column;

// Table data as a list of array.
var rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b3', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']
];

function rowGetter(rowIndex) {
  return rows[rowIndex];
}
React.render(
  <Table
    rowHeight={50}
    rowGetter={rowGetter}
    rowsCount={rows.length}
    width={5000}
    height={5000}
    headerHeight={50}>
    <Column
      label="Col 1"
      width={3000}
      dataKey={0}
    />
    <Column
      label="Col 2"
      width={2000}
      dataKey={1}
    />
  </Table>,
  document.getElementById('table')
);
```

I'm using the tutorial sample code from react.js to start off with:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial

Here's the link to fixed-data-table:

https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact requirements but if you want something simple and flexible, maybe [reactabular](https://bebraw.github.io/reactabular/) would work.

Comment: You need to use [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) to load up the fixed table module, so that you can `require` it in the React code. [Here](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) is a short guide on it.

Comment: Does reactabular support grouped columns?

Comment: @jimjampez Not yet. I set up [an issue](https://github.com/bebraw/reactabular/issues/33) where to discuss that.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Trying to get a fixed table component example rendered  from the react.js tutorial code. Perhaps I create a github repo to make it more clear?